# WinUI3 - how to add an icon to the SplitButton in a CommandBar?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I am just starting with WinUI3.  I am trying to add an icon to a SplitButton on a CommandBar like I can with a XamlUICommand and AppBarButton.  There doesn't appear to be an Icon property for SplitButton.

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.ActivityPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*, 50" x:Name="ContentArea">
        <CommandBar Background="Transparent" IsOpen="False" DefaultLabelPosition="Right" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <AppBarButton x:Name="EditJob" Command="{StaticResource UICmdEditJob}"/>
            <AppBarElementContainer>
                <SplitButton Content="Estimate">
                    <SplitButton.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout Placement="RightEdgeAlignedTop">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="View Estimate"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Print Estimate"/>
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </SplitButton.Flyout>
                </SplitButton>
            </AppBarElementContainer>
```

How can I add an icon to a SplitButton like on a regular AppBarButton?  I am trying to use the Segoe Fluent Icon font.  Thanks a lot.

I tried a number of ways to add an icon and all came up short since there is no SplitButton.Icon property from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a `FontIcon` and a `TextBlock` as the `SplitButton`'s `Content`:

```xml
<SplitButton>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--  Content  -->
        <FontIcon
            Grid.Column="0"
            FontSize="16"
            Glyph="&#xE8E1;" />
        <TextBlock
            Margin="8,0,0,0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="Estimate" />
    </Grid>
    <SplitButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="RightEdgeAlignedTop">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="View Estimate" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Print Estimate" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </SplitButton.Flyout>
</SplitButton>
```